# "Hitting all red lights" meaning?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

I came across this sentence.

> Hitting all red lights can feel very unlucky.

"Hit" basically means to deal a blow or strike to, but I guess the meaning
of "hit" here is "meet" or "be caught in".

Why do people use this word 'hit' not using more proper word?

Comment: "Why do people use this word 'hit' not using more proper word?" - Because proper language isn't very interesting, and people like to be interesting

Comment: I think there's also a brevity to using "hit" -- think of the alternatives. "It can feel unlucky to ... have all the lights turn red when you arrive at them"? "have all lights be red when you reach them"? At least in the US, and I suspect in other cultures as well, people tend to use, or even create, shorter forms of things.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, you have the right idea of what *hit* means here. From M-W,

> [hit](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hit)
>   5 :  to discover or meet especially by chance • prospectors *hitting* gold • *hit* a snowstorm while driving home • *hit* a run of bad luck

It is an idiomatic usage of the word *hit*. So in that sense, it is "proper": it makes sense. We can rephrase it with a more formal word, like *encounter*

> Encountering all red lights can feel very unlucky.

but in a causal setting, *hit* would seem more fitting. Also, *hitting the red lights* seems more impactful than *encountering*, for example, if a writer wanted to convey that naunce.

Comment: Additionally, to *hit* a red light implies some level of interaction (even if you're not literally hitting it), while an *encounter* can be more passive. A pedestrian, for example, may *encounter* a red light for cars, but be entirely unaffected by it - while at the next crossing, he might *hit* a red light at the pedestrian crossing, preventing him from crossing the road.

Comment: It's not even that idiomatic in this usage considering if you "hit a red light" it stops you when otherwise you would have kept driving through.

Answer (score 0):

In Britain, "hit the lights" often means "go to an area where bars and nightclubs are open and have bright light adverts.

Comment: That is not the meaning here.